# How do you ask "who" which is "wer", but for plural things such as people?

Tags: grammar

Can you say for example "Wer sind sie?" or do you use something else for that question?

Comment: Hey and welcome to the German Language StackExchange. If you like, you can take the [tour] or browse through the [help] if the need arises. Have fun! :)

Answer (score 5):

"Wer" is correct in plural. so "Wer sind sie?" is also a correct sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The word "wer" is correct, but if you are trying to ask "who are those people?", you should better use something like "wer sind *diese Leute*?", instead of "wer sind *sie*?".

The latter sounds way more natural ;)

Comment: Hey and welcome to the German Language StackExchange. If you want, you can take a look at the [tour] or browse through the [help]. Have a nice day! :)